# Runtime error - dydld: Symbol not found: __ZNSsD1Ev

Tags: c++, linker, libstdc++, clang++, libc++

Getting this error at runtime when trying to load dynamic library. 
I know it's something with std::strings is missing and connected with libc++ vs libstdc++. 
Would appreciate, if anyone could explain exactly what's going on and why.

**Compiler flags:** `-fshort-wchar -fPIC -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7`

**Linker flags:** `-Wl, -dynamiclib -undefined suppress -flat_namespace`

MacOS X 10.9.4
Clang++: Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)

Comment: Looks like `__ZNSsD1Ev` refers to the string destructor (according to demangler.com)

Comment: thanks! however i still don't know why is this happening